# How do I resolve Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 error with clang++ building Octave from source on Catalina?

Tags: octave, linker-errors, clang++

I am building Octave from source code on OS X 10.15.7

The linker is generating numerous errors:
E.g.

```
  "bsxfun_add(intNDArray<octave_int<signed char> > const&, intNDArray<octave_int<signed char> > const&)", referenced from:
      octave_value bsxfun_forward_op<intNDArray<octave_int<signed char> >, &(bsxfun_add(intNDArray<octave_int<signed char> > const&, intNDArray<octave_int<signed char> > const&))>(octave_value const&, octave_value const&) in libcorefcn.a(libcorefcn_la-bsxfun.o)
```

Here's my build environment settings:

```
$ xcrun --show-sdk-path
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk

(base) MacBook-Pro:.build davidlaxer$ xcode-select -p
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools

$ clang++ --version
Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

Here's my 'configuration' command for Octave:

```
../configure \
CC=/usr/bin/clang \
CXX=/usr/bin/clang++ \
CCLD=/usr/bin/clang \
CXXLD=/usr/bin/clang++ \
F77=/opt/local/bin/gfortran-mp-10 \
FFLAGS="-pipe -Os -m64" \
CFLAGS="-isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk" \
CCFLAGS="-isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk" \
CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/local/include -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk -I/Users/davidlaxer/SuiteSparse/include -I/opt/local/libexec/qt5/include -I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-13.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/include" \
CXXFLAGS="-pipe -Os -std=c++17 -stdlib=libc++ -arch x86_64 -pthread -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk" LDFLAGS="-L/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/lib -L/Users/davidlaxer/SuiteSparse/lib/ -L/opt/local/libexec/qt5/lib -L/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-13.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/lib -arch x86_64" DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="-L/opt/local/lib -L/opt/local/libexec/qt5/lib -L/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-13.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/lib" LD_LIBRARY_PATH="-L/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/lib -L/Users/davidlaxer/SuiteSparse/lib/ -L/opt/local/lib -L/opt/local/libexec/qt5/lib -L/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-13.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/lib" --with-suitesparseconfig-includedir=/Users/davidlaxer/SuiteSparse/include --with-suitesparseconfig-libdir=/Users/davidlaxer/SuiteSparse/lib --disable-readline  --with-sundials_ida-includedir=/opt/local/include/sundials --with-sundials_ida-libdir=/opt/local/lib/ --with-qt=5 --with-libiconv-prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr --with-qhull-includedir=/opt/local/include/libqhull --with-qhull-libdir=/opt/local/lib --with-hdf5-includedir=/opt/local/include --with-hdf5-libdir=/opt/local/lib
```

There are compiler warnings regarding DEPRECATED functions but it seems unrelated.

```
  CXX      libinterp/corefcn/libcorefcn_la-bsxfun.lo
../libinterp/corefcn/bsxfun.cc:543:31: warning: 'do_cat_op' is deprecated
      [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                          C = do_cat_op (C, tmp(0), ra_idx);
                              ^
../libinterp/octave-value/ov.h:1713:1: note: 'do_cat_op' has been explicitly
      marked deprecated here
OCTAVE_DEPRECATED (7, "use 'octave::cat_op' instead")
^
```

The symbols the linker is complaining about are in the object file and static library:

```
$ nm -n ../.build/libinterp/corefcn/.libs/libcorefcn_la-bsxfun.o | grep bsxfun_add
                 U __Z10bsxfun_addRK10intNDArrayI10octave_intIaEES4_
                 U __Z10bsxfun_addRK10intNDArrayI10octave_intIhEES4_
                 U __Z10bsxfun_addRK10intNDArrayI10octave_intIiEES4_
                 U __Z10bsxfun_addRK10intNDArrayI10octave_intIjEES4_
                 U __Z10bsxfun_addRK10intNDArrayI10octave_intIsEES4_
                 U __Z10bsxfun_addRK10intNDArrayI10octave_intItEES4_
                 U __Z10bsxfun_addRK10intNDArrayI10octave_intIxEES4_
                 U __Z10bsxfun_addRK10intNDArrayI10octave_intIyEES4_
                 U __Z10bsxfun_addRK12FloatNDArrayS1_
                 U __Z10bsxfun_addRK14ComplexNDArrayS1_
                 U __Z10bsxfun_addRK19FloatComplexNDArrayS1_
                 U __Z10bsxfun_addRK7NDArrayS1_
0000000000004a35 t __ZL17bsxfun_forward_opI7NDArrayXadL_Z10bsxfun_addRKS0_S2_EEE12octave_valueRKS3_S5_
0000000000005311 t __ZL17bsxfun_forward_opI12FloatNDArrayXadL_Z10bsxfun_addRKS0_S2_EEE12octave_valueRKS3_S5_
0000000000005bed t __ZL17bsxfun_forward_opI14ComplexNDArrayXadL_Z10bsxfun_addRKS0_S2_EEE12octave_valueRKS3_S5_
00000000000064c9 t __ZL17bsxfun_forward_opI19FloatComplexNDArrayXadL_Z10bsxfun_addRKS0_S2_EEE12octave_valueRKS3_S5_
0000000000006da5 t __ZL17bsxfun_forward_opI10intNDArrayI10octave_intIaEEXadL_Z10bsxfun_addRKS3_S5_EEE12octave_valueRKS6_S8_
0000000000007651 t __ZL17bsxfun_forward_opI10intNDArrayI10octave_intIsEEXadL_Z10bsxfun_addRKS3_S5_EEE12octave_valueRKS6_S8_
0000000000007efd t __ZL17bsxfun_forward_opI10intNDArrayI10octave_intIiEEXadL_Z10bsxfun_addRKS3_S5_EEE12octave_valueRKS6_S8_
00000000000087a9 t __ZL17bsxfun_forward_opI10intNDArrayI10octave_intIxEEXadL_Z10bsxfun_addRKS3_S5_EEE12octave_valueRKS6_S8_
0000000000009055 t __ZL17bsxfun_forward_opI10intNDArrayI10octave_intIhEEXadL_Z10bsxfun_addRKS3_S5_EEE12octave_valueRKS6_S8_
0000000000009901 t __ZL17bsxfun_forward_opI10intNDArrayI10octave_intItEEXadL_Z10bsxfun_addRKS3_S5_EEE12octave_valueRKS6_S8_
000000000000a1ad t __ZL17bsxfun_forward_opI10intNDArrayI10octave_intIjEEXadL_Z10bsxfun_addRKS3_S5_EEE12octave_valueRKS6_S8_
000000000000aa59 t __ZL17bsxfun_forward_opI10intNDArrayI10octave_intIyEEXadL_Z10bsxfun_addRKS3_S5_EEE12octave_valueRKS6_S8_
```

and

```
$ nm -n ../.build/libinterp/corefcn/.libs/libcorefcn.a | grep bsxfun_add
                 U __Z10bsxfun_addRK10intNDArrayI10octave_intIaEES4_
                 U __Z10bsxfun_addRK10intNDArrayI10octave_intIhEES4_
                 U __Z10bsxfun_addRK10intNDArrayI10octave_intIiEES4_
                 U __Z10bsxfun_addRK10intNDArrayI10octave_intIjEES4_
                 U __Z10bsxfun_addRK10intNDArrayI10octave_intIsEES4_
                 U __Z10bsxfun_addRK10intNDArrayI10octave_intItEES4_
                 U __Z10bsxfun_addRK10intNDArrayI10octave_intIxEES4_
                 U __Z10bsxfun_addRK10intNDArrayI10octave_intIyEES4_
                 U __Z10bsxfun_addRK12FloatNDArrayS1_
                 U __Z10bsxfun_addRK14ComplexNDArrayS1_
                 U __Z10bsxfun_addRK19FloatComplexNDArrayS1_
                 U __Z10bsxfun_addRK7NDArrayS1_
0000000000004a7d t __ZL17bsxfun_forward_opI7NDArrayXadL_Z10bsxfun_addRKS0_S2_EEE12octave_valueRKS3_S5_
0000000000005359 t __ZL17bsxfun_forward_opI12FloatNDArrayXadL_Z10bsxfun_addRKS0_S2_EEE12octave_valueRKS3_S5_
0000000000005c35 t __ZL17bsxfun_forward_opI14ComplexNDArrayXadL_Z10bsxfun_addRKS0_S2_EEE12octave_valueRKS3_S5_
0000000000006511 t __ZL17bsxfun_forward_opI19FloatComplexNDArrayXadL_Z10bsxfun_addRKS0_S2_EEE12octave_valueRKS3_S5_
0000000000006ded t __ZL17bsxfun_forward_opI10intNDArrayI10octave_intIaEEXadL_Z10bsxfun_addRKS3_S5_EEE12octave_valueRKS6_S8_
0000000000007699 t __ZL17bsxfun_forward_opI10intNDArrayI10octave_intIsEEXadL_Z10bsxfun_addRKS3_S5_EEE12octave_valueRKS6_S8_
0000000000007f45 t __ZL17bsxfun_forward_opI10intNDArrayI10octave_intIiEEXadL_Z10bsxfun_addRKS3_S5_EEE12octave_valueRKS6_S8_
00000000000087f1 t __ZL17bsxfun_forward_opI10intNDArrayI10octave_intIxEEXadL_Z10bsxfun_addRKS3_S5_EEE12octave_valueRKS6_S8_
000000000000909d t __ZL17bsxfun_forward_opI10intNDArrayI10octave_intIhEEXadL_Z10bsxfun_addRKS3_S5_EEE12octave_valueRKS6_S8_
0000000000009949 t __ZL17bsxfun_forward_opI10intNDArrayI10octave_intItEEXadL_Z10bsxfun_addRKS3_S5_EEE12octave_valueRKS6_S8_
000000000000a1f5 t __ZL17bsxfun_forward_opI10intNDArrayI10octave_intIjEEXadL_Z10bsxfun_addRKS3_S5_EEE12octave_valueRKS6_S8_
000000000000aaa1 t __ZL17bsxfun_forward_opI10intNDArrayI10octave_intIyEEXadL_Z10bsxfun_addRKS3_S5_EEE12octave_valueRKS6_S8_
```

The mangled names in the object file and the static library appear to be slightly different from the one in compile warning:

demangled with http://demangler.com:

```
_octave_value bsxfun_forward_op<NDArray, &(bsxfun_add(NDArray const&, NDArray const&))>(octave_value const&, octave_value const&)
```

Linker error (undefined symbol):

```
 octave_value bsxfun_forward_op<intNDArray<octave_int<signed char> >, &(bsxfun_add(intNDArray<octave_int<signed char> > const&, intNDArray<octave_int<signed char> > const&))>(octave_value const&, octave_value const&)
```

Easier viewing:
[image]

Here's the linker command:

```
/usr/bin/clang++ -v -dynamiclib  -o libinterp/.libs/liboctinterp.8.dylib  libinterp/.libs/liboctinterp_la-octave.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-b-b.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-b-bm.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-b-sbm.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-bm-b.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-bm-bm.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-bm-sbm.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-cdm-cdm.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-cdm-cm.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-cdm-cs.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-cdm-dm.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-cdm-m.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-cdm-s.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-cell.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-chm.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-class.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-cm-cdm.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-cm-cm.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-cm-cs.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-cm-dm.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-cm-m.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-cm-pm.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-cm-s.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-cm-scm.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-cm-sm.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-cs-cm.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-cs-cs.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-cs-m.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-cs-s.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-cs-scm.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-cs-sm.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-dm-cdm.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-dm-cm.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-dm-cs.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-dm-dm.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-dm-m.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-dm-s.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-dm-scm.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-dm-sm.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-fcdm-fcdm.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-fcdm-fcm.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-fcdm-fcs.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-fcdm-fdm.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-fcdm-fm.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-fcdm-fs.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-fcm-fcdm.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-fcm-fcm.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-fcm-fcs.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-fcm-fdm.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-fcm-fm.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-fcm-fs.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-fcm-pm.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-fcn.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-fcs-fcm.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-fcs-fcs.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-fcs-fm.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-fcs-fs.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-fdm-fcdm.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-fdm-fcm.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-fdm-fcs.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-fdm-fdm.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-fdm-fm.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-fdm-fs.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-fm-fcdm.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-fm-fcm.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-fm-fcs.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-fm-fdm.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-fm-fm.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-fm-fs.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-fm-pm.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-fs-fcm.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-fs-fcs.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-fs-fm.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-fs-fs.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-i16-i16.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-i32-i32.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-i64-i64.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-i8-i8.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-int-concat.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-m-cdm.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-m-cm.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-m-cs.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-m-dm.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-m-m.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-m-pm.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-m-s.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-m-scm.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-m-sm.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-mi.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-pm-cm.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-pm-fcm.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-pm-fm.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-pm-m.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-pm-pm.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-pm-scm.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-pm-sm.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-range.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-s-cm.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-s-cs.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-s-m.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-s-s.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-s-scm.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-s-sm.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-sbm-b.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-sbm-bm.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-sbm-sbm.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-scm-cm.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-scm-cs.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-scm-m.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-scm-s.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-scm-scm.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-scm-sm.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-sm-cm.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-sm-cs.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-sm-m.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-sm-s.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-sm-scm.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-sm-sm.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-str-m.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-str-s.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-str-str.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-struct.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-ui16-ui16.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-ui32-ui32.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-ui64-ui64.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-op-ui8-ui8.o libinterp/template-inst/.libs/liboctinterp_la-Array-tc.o libinterp/template-inst/.libs/liboctinterp_la-Array-jit.o libinterp/.libs/liboctinterp_la-build-env-features.o libinterp/.libs/liboctinterp_la-build-env.o libinterp/.libs/liboctinterp_la-builtins.o libinterp/corefcn/.libs/liboctinterp_la-oct-errno.o libinterp/.libs/liboctinterp_la-liboctinterp-build-info.o libinterp/operators/.libs/liboctinterp_la-ops.o   -Wl,-force_load,libinterp/octave-value/.libs/liboctave-value.a -Wl,-force_load,libinterp/parse-tree/.libs/libparse-tree.a -Wl,-force_load,libinterp/corefcn/.libs/libcorefcn.a  -L/opt/local/lib -L/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/lib -L/Users/davidlaxer/SuiteSparse/lib/ -L/opt/local/libexec/qt5/lib -L/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-13.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/lib liboctave/.libs/liboctave.dylib -L/opt/local/lib/gcc10/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin19/10.2.0 -L/opt/local/lib/gcc10/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin19/10.2.0/../../.. -liconv -lhdf5 -lGraphicsMagick++ -lGraphicsMagick -lz -framework OpenGL -lfontconfig -lfreetype -L/opt/X11/lib -lX11 -framework Carbon -lgl2ps -lcurl -lcholmod -lumfpack -lamd -lcamd -lcolamd -lccolamd -lcxsparse -lsuitesparseconfig -lspqr -larpack -lfftw3_threads -lfftw3 -lfftw3f_threads -lfftw3f -llapack -lblas -lncurses -lpcre -ldl -lgfortran -lquadmath -lm  -pthread -Os -stdlib=libc++ -arch x86_64 -pthread -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk -arch x86_64 -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation   -pthread -framework OpenGL -framework Carbon -install_name  /usr/local/lib/octave/7.0.0/liboctinterp.8.dylib -compatibility_version 9 -current_version 9.0 -Wl,-single_module
```

Comment: this question seems fairly specialised ... you may be better off asking directly at https://octave.discourse.group/, octave mailing list, IRC, etc.

Comment: Thanks.  I opened an issue on Savannah but the OS X version apparently has unresolved issues.  I got the Macport's build which builds on Catalina with my SDKs.  Curiously the manged names in the symbol tabl are identical between my build and the MacPort build in the static library: ../.build/libinterp/corefcn/.libs/libcorefcn.a. It's the same linker, the linker parameter are slightly different.  One difference: --std=c++17 -vs --stdlib=gnu++11.  But when I tried gnu++11 I had the same issue(s).